# Empty Firmware Password?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, security, firmware-password

I was wanting to reveal the EFI password on my Mac using this in the Terminal:

```
sudo nvram security-password
```

but instead of outputting hex data, it gives me this:

```
nvram: Error getting variable - 'security': (iokit/common) data was not found
```

I know there is a FW password because I get the lock when holding `Option` on boot. Any ideas why this isn't working? I have admin access.

Macbook Pro 13-Inch w/ Retina Display, Mid-2014, running 10.10.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The firmware password on newer machines isn't stored in nvram anymore (which is why anything newer than around 2010/2011 cannot have the firmware password removed by reseating RAM).

<sup>Source: https://github.com/munkireport/munkireport-php/issues/43#issuecomment-29738033</sup>

Comment: OK. Any idea where is it stored now? I looked at the EFI partition by mounting it, not there either. Thanks for the quick reply btw :-)

Comment: It's stored in a separate controller chip that AIUI also stores the boot ROM firmware itself. There is no way to read the firmware password out of this chip (at least without desoldering the chip), and resetting it is ... complicated. See [this c|net article](http://www.cnet.com/news/efi-firmware-protection-locks-down-newer-macs/).